# MYSQL Reverse "filesystem" iteration

Tags: mysql, sql, jasper-reports

I am using *iReport* to build a report and I am trying to find the parent node "group_name" value based on a parent_group_id given, and return the value the parent, as the child's value.

For example:

Table: t1

```
               id                    |              parent_group_id          |  group_name
22ba9b80-303d-11e3-8108-002590ac9042 |  NULL                                 |  Audio
37fdf930-34f5-11e3-8108-002590ac9042 |  22ba9b80-303d-11e3-8108-002590ac9042 |  Audio Cables and bits
252ecfd0-303d-11e3-8108-002590ac9042 |  25824700-303d-11e3-8108-002590ac9042 |  Audio Headphones
26858630-303d-11e3-8108-002590ac9042 |  22ba9b80-303d-11e3-8108-002590ac9042 |  Audio Interfaces
d3e962b0-3dcb-11e3-883d-002590ac9042 |  3aa35f70-3691-11e3-8108-002590ac9042 |  Audio Recording Stock
2d735bc0-303d-11e3-8108-002590ac9042 |  22ba9b80-303d-11e3-8108-002590ac9042 |  Audio Roadcases
```

So if I wanted to get the 'group_name' of the second item, I want it to return "Audio", and not "Audio Cables and bits". If I wanted to get the 'group_name" of the third item, it should also return -some other unlisted value-, and so forth

Is there a way to do this with any of the xml, sql, or *Java* features with *JasperReports*, or is it possible to do with SQL alone?

I'm essentially looking to recursively iterate backwards through multiple file systems (there will be more than 1 "root" file, however, with different names) and for each child, I want that child's root "group_name" to replace the child's actual "group_name"

Edit- i updated the table with a sample of the actual values- notice how some of them have the same "parent_group_id" as the one with the null parent_group_id ? I want those ones, instead of saying "Audio Cables and bits", etc, to say "Audio", the parent of the directory

Answer (score 0):

You can get it by SQL ways.
Try it:

```
SELECT parent.group_name FROM Group child LEFT JOIN Group parent ON (child.parent_id = parent.id) WHERE child.id = '01';
```

Comment: Kinda have the right idea but not quite there- I'm looking to recursively iterate backwards through *multiple* file systems (there will be more than 1 "root" file, however, with different names) and for each child, I want that child's root "group_name" to replace the child's actual "group_name"